# type name `int` is undefined or not in scope

Tags: rust

What does this mean?

```
error: type name `int` is undefined or not in scope
```

I am trying to compile this [example](http://kukuruku.co/hub/rust/comparing-rust-and-cpp):

```
fn minval(A: &[int]) -> int {
  A.iter().fold(A[0], |u,&a| {
    if a<u {a} else {u}
  })
}

fn main() {
    let A = [1i,2i,3i];
    let min = minval(A.as_slice());
    println!("{}", min);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `int` type in Rust. Rust has the following integer types:

- `i8`, `i16`, `i32`, `i64`, `i128`: signed integer with 8/16/32/64/128 bits
- `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64`, `u128`: **un**signed integer with 8/16/32/64/128 bits
- `isize`, `usize`: signed/unsigned integer with pointer size (64 bit on 64 bit systems)

You can learn more about this in [this chapter of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/primitive-types.html#numeric-types).

Comment: so this means the example from that website is not in rust?

Comment: Where did you find the example? Can you link the website?

Comment: Yes, the link is in the question

Comment: I think Rust may have had `int` in 2014 (when that article was written), and was changed to `isize` sometime before 1.0

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, haven't seen that. Yes the website's example is no valid Rust `1.x`. The article on the website was written a few months before Rust was officially released and I think that Rust had `int` at that time still. Information on Rust that was written before May 2015 is probably outdated :/